# How to setup connection between RDS database and EC2 instance via cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I'm able to create an EC2 instance and an RDS db via the cdk but can't find out how to connect them outside of the aws console.

When setting up the connection manually I get the screen that describes the changes saying "To set up a connection between the database and the EC2 instance, VPC security group xxx-xxx-x is added to the database, and VPC security group xxx-xxx-x is added to the EC2 instance."

Is there a way to do this via cdk?

Is it possible to do this in the `instanceProps` of the DatabaseCluster?
My existing code for the RDS db cluster looks something like this:

```
this.dbCluster = new DatabaseCluster(this, 'MyDbCluster',{
 // 
 instanceProps: { vpc: props.vpc, vpcSubnets: { subGroupName: 'private' } }
})
```

How would I add the group to my existing code for the EC2 instance - in the vpcSubnets section?

```
const ec2Instance = new Instance( this, 'ec2instance', {
 //
 vpcSubnets: {
                  subnetGroupName: 'private',
            },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow EC2 to connect to RDS.

You do this by using the `DatabaseCluster.connections` prop ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.DatabaseCluster.html#connections)).

Look at the examples in the [Connections class docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Connections.html#example).

```
this.dbCluster.connections.allowFrom(ec2Instance, ec2.Port.tcp(5432));
```

*Adjust the port to match your database flavor port.*

Comment: Or better yet - don't worry about the port altogether and use `connections.allowDefaultPortFrom(ec2Instance);`